# Cannot access realm that has been closed

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

**“Error: Cannot access realm that has been closed.”**
Hello community,I encountered an unexpected error while attempting to open a Realm instance. The error message states: “Cannot access realm that has been closed.” This issue is perplexing because the application has been working flawlessly until today. I am seeking assistance from the community to help me resolve this error.

I am attempting to create a new document using Realm. However, I encountered an issue as the Realm instance failed to open. Consequently, I am unable to write the document as intended. My expectation was to successfully open the Realm instance in order to proceed with document creation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see this is a cross post to the Realm Forums but in general, when asking questions code should be provided and your troubleshooting should be included. As is - this could be a simple coding or logic issue... or something deeper but anything we suggest would be a total guess without more info. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)